Testing CredentialsManager implementation on android emulators
Having implemented Google Sign-In in my Android app using CredentialsManager API (and successfully working on my own Pixel device) I'm not testing on Android emulators (with Google APIs). The emulator is signed in with my Google account.
However, credentialManager.getCredential(context, request) is throwing NoCredentialException.
My credentialOption is:
val googleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
    .setServerClientId(webClientId)
    .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
.build()

On another emulator, I got GetCredentialProviderConfigurationException instead.
Is this a problem with the emulators or with my implementation?
EDIT: This is not a Android SDK level issue because everything works fine on all Android SDK levels when using emulators that include the Google Play APIs.

Here are my own findings. I won't accept my own answer in case someone can provide a better one.
Google APIs emulator images for Android 13 use Play Services 22.50.14 which does not support Google Sign In. Android 14 & 15 Google APIs images have a more recent version (23.18.18) and work fine. Google Play APIs images support updating the Play Services version, so also work fine after updating.

Looks like version GMS 23.08.15 is required for this feature to work

For Android 13 and below, an additional package is required:
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.1"

    implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.2.2"

    // implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials-e2ee:1.0.0-alpha02"
    // testImplementation "org.playframework:play-test_3:3.0.4"
}

Also see the documentation.

Thanks, but I'm already using that. There is no problem with emulators that include the Google Play APIs regardless of Android SDK level.

And this might even be the expected behavior, when running on emulators without Play Services; there's usually two kinds of images, Play Services & Google APIs. The question only shows the options, not the sign-in flow: https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg#enable-sign-in

See the FAQ: "Can developers merge their sign-up and sign-in flows into one API call using Credential Manager?" -> "Not planned right now." (the same sign-in flow with or without Play Services that might be)... try GetPasswordOption instead; GetGoogleIdOption might depend on Play Services.

This might also depend on library googleid. GetCredentialProviderConfigurationException reads: "During the get credential flow, this is thrown when configurations are mismatched for the provider, typically indicating the provider dependency is missing in the manifest or some system service is not enabled."

Just to be clear, "Google API" emulator images include Google Play Services. So it's more the version of Google Play Services (rather than the existence of it) that is the issue here.

It's not the same, it may have (outdated) Play Services, but no Play Store app. and it's rooted. May you'd have to unroot it? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#system-image I mean, there must be some difference ...and the Play Images are for "Play Services, Google Login Procedures, Admob".

Is it not just that Google Play Store needs to be at least a version for Sign In With Google to work? That's the hypothesis I'm working, and the one I gave in my answer.
